# react-native-router-flux backAndroidHandler not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am working on a react-native mobile application where I have used `react-native-router-flux`
I have a scene as below

```
1- Screen1
2- Screen2
3- Screen3
4- Screen4
```

when I press android backbutton on screen 4 it goes to screen 3 then 2 then 1
but when I press android backbutton on screen1 it should exit from the application, but its not working

Here is my Router Stack

```
<Router navigationBarStyle={styles.navBar} titleStyle={styles.navTitle} navBarTintColor={'white'} navBarButtonImageColor={'white'} tintColor={'white'} sceneStyle={styles.routerScene} >
        <Stack key="root">
          <Scene
            key="Screen1"
            component={Screen1}
            animation="fade"
            hideNavBar={true}
            initial={true}
            type='replace'
          />
          <Scene
            key="Screen2"
            component={Screen2}
            animation="fade"
            hideNavBar={true}
            type='replace'
          />
          <Scene
            key="Screen3"
            component={Screen3}
            title="Enrollment"
            animation="slide"
            hideNavBar={false}
            type='replace'
          />
          <Scene
            key="Screen4"
            component={Screen4}
            title="Enrollment"
            animation="slide"
            hideNavBar={false}
            type='replace'
          />
```

I also tried using below code

```
componentWillMount(){
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress.bind(this));
    }

  onBackPress() {
        if (backButtonPressedOnceToExit) {
            BackAndroid.exitApp();
        } else {
            if (Actions.currentScene !== 'Home') {
                Actions.pop();
                return true;
            } else {
                backButtonPressedOnceToExit = true;
                ToastAndroid.show("Press Back Button again to exit",ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                //setting timeout is optional
                setTimeout( () => { backButtonPressedOnceToExit = false }, 2000);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

and when I try to debug this my debugger doesn't go inside the function.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is it because of this line `setTimeout( () => { backButtonPressedOnceToExit = false }, 2000);` that reset the `backButtonPressedOnceToExit` flag before you press back to exit?

Comment: @max23_ I tried removing this but doesn't work, even my debugger is not going to that function

Comment: When you say "debugger is not going to that function", do you mean `onBackPress()`?

Comment: There was some issue with my react server after restarting it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `backAndroidHandler` prop of `Router` component.

`<Router navigationBarStyle={styles.navBar} titleStyle={styles.navTitle} navBarTintColor={'white'} navBarButtonImageColor={'white'} tintColor={'white'} sceneStyle={styles.routerScene} backAndroidHandler={this.onBackPress}>`

and in `onBackPress`, you mentioned the wrong screen. `Home` is not present in your router stack. Make it `Screen1`. Also 'return true` in first if condition.

Comment: Hi I tried your changes, unfortunately its not working.

Comment: @suneel Can you remove `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` and make `onBackPress` an arrow function? Also once changes are done, can you post your updated code somewhere? pastebin.com / hastebin.com

Comment: There was some issue with my react server after restarting it works fine.
but thanks for pointing in right direction